# Taking latest details of a colum with different column type in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with same records type of data for multiple users

```
examscoreid | examscorenum | examresult | userid | examtype
55                 89             P        7760       1 
54                 78             P        7760       3 
53                 90             P        7760       5 
52                 89             P        7760       4
41                 80             P        7666       2
44                 80             P        7666       2
```

I need the examscorenum with different examtype  and latest examscoreid with examtype grouped

Result should be like

```
   examscoreid | examscorenum | examresult |     userid | examtype
    55                 89             P        7760       1 
    54                 78             P        7760       3 
    53                 90             P        7760       5 
    44                 80             P        7666       2
```

See the userid 7666 has got two rows with same examtype but the reequired result should contain latest exam scoreid (44 taken not 41)

Similarly I need the whole users data

Sample Query

```
SELECT examscorenum  FROM `exams` WHERE userid in (7760,7666) group by examtype,userid order by examscoreid desc
```

I get the data but for userid 7666 i get results of examscoreid 41 not 44

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking for. Could you post an expected result?

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I have updated the code . Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about the following:

```
create table #exams
(
    examscoreid int,
    examscorenum int,
    examresult varchar(1),
    userid int,
    examtype int
)

insert into #exams values(55, 89, 'P', 7760, 1)
insert into #exams values(54, 78, 'P', 7760, 3)
insert into #exams values(53, 90, 'P', 7760, 5)
insert into #exams values(52, 89, 'P', 7760, 4)
insert into #exams values(41, 80, 'P', 7666, 2)
insert into #exams values(44, 80, 'P', 7666, 2)

SELECT distinct t1.examscoreid, t1.examscorenum, t1.examresult, t1.userid, t1.examtype 
FROM #exams t1
JOIN 
(
    select userid, max(examscoreid) as maxscoreid, examtype
    from #exams 
    group by userid, examtype
) t2
    on t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE t1.userid in (7760,7666) 
    AND t1.examscoreid = t2.maxscoreid
order by t1.examscoreid desc

drop table #exams
```